# Require module from folder with dot in name

Tags: lua

I would like to require file from a folder that has dot (.) in name:

```
"Folder.ai/test.lua"
```

If the folder would not have dot in name I would use:

```
require(Folder.test)
```

How should I do it when the dot is there?

Comment: I think you can add custom loader/searchers https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loaders

Answer (score 5):

`require` looks for files using loaders, you can add a custom loader by inserting the function into `package.loaders`.

Your custom loader might look like this:

```
local function load(modulename)
  local errmsg = ""
  for path in string.gmatch(package.path, "([^;]+)") do
    local filename = string.gsub(path, "%?", modulename)
    local file = io.open(filename, "rb")
    if file then
      -- Compile and return the module
      return assert(loadstring(assert(file:read("*a")), filename))
    end
    errmsg = errmsg.."\n\tno file '"..filename.."' (checked with custom loader)"
  end
  return errmsg
end

table.insert(package.loaders, 2, load) -- this will run before the standard loader, if you want it to
                                       -- run after you can call table.insert(package.loaders, load)
```

> Resource: http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaModulesLoader